# Different background size in different browser

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have this site: http://uggerhojimprove.dk and when I visit from my phone, the size of the background image is changing after which browser I use. So when I use Firefox for Android it's a good fit but when I use Chrome the size is much bigger and doesn't look good.

Can anyone tell me what to do? [image: From firefox][image: from chrome]

Comment: The thing to do in cases like this is create a [mcve] - that is, take the page and prune it down to the absolute minimum required to demonstrate the problem. Then it will be much easier to debug. Who knows, maybe you yourself will find what the problem is in the process.

Comment: So what you're saying is, that there's no easy-to-see mistake in codes? ;)

Comment: Quite possibly, yes. All you need to do is look at each of the 12 included stylesheets thoroughly, at the big minified style block in the html file itself and at the many scripts to see if they don't introduce any anomalous behaviour.

Comment: Okay. I thought it was because Chrome and Firefox maybe didn't "understand" the same code (moz and webkit) and I just needed to write an extra line :(

Comment: I see now, that many on the internet have this problem in chrome. As if chrome don't understand the `background-attachment: fixed;` code.